# Data filtering with uiRouter best practice

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I have an Angular application with uiRouter and some data that I want to display using Angular-Chart.js.

I have different filters that can be applied to this data. I also want to have a URL that represents the state with all applied filters, i.e. /:groupId/:dateStart/:dateEnd

Right now I have a state with parameters, and two views (controller+template) - one for displaying data and one for displaying filters. In the filterController, I have a function that is called when the filter is changed, and that function simply calls $state.go("Controller", newFilterParams);

That approach works, however, that fully reloads the controller for the data, and I want to prevent it and animate the data change. But I also want to preserve the URL representation.

Is that possible? What would be the best practice to implement data filtering in Angular and uiRouter?

Comment: Suppose one will not provide `:groupId` in the url, would the url be like so: `//:dateStart/:dateEnd`? or are you looking for a clean solution `/:dateStart/:dateEnd` (notice the missing `/`)?

Comment: @MuliYulzary I can have the default parameter for that, i.e. /default/timestamp/1461948564/1461950000